# Is it possible to get an 'S' rank?

Tags: resident-evil-6

Is it possible to get an 'S' rank in Resident Evil 6? If so, what are the general requirements? I know some will probably be subjective to the level (time and enemies) but what about accuracy and deaths? is there a set rule for an 'S' rank? (assuming it is even possible)

This was the case in most of previous games. So far my best is an A rank, and I suppose the closest I have to knowing if an 'S' rank is possible is that my number of deaths was at 1 (which gave me an 'A' rank) and I wonder if 0 deaths would be an 'S' rank.

Anybody got anything better than an A?

Comment: I imagine you're talking about the mercenary mode?

Comment: No I mean the campaign mode (there is no 'deaths' count for mercenaries), but it would also be good to know if mercenaries has an 'S' rank too. I would imagine if one does, then they all do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I do not own the game, someone took the time to upload a set of videos where they play through chapter 1 on professional (so they have a bunch of things unlocked, making everything much easier).

If you look at [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nGwPZpcCmU) [three](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZLkjhXphkk) [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8JUn4dVN8g), you can see them attain an S rank on that chapter, with relevant tips.

The important bit, though, is probably this:
[image: Criteria?]

While the above aren't necessarily the minimum criteria for an S rank, you will definitely attain one if you are at least that good (on that specific chapter, it obviously makes sense that the criteria are different for different chapters).

Comment: OK so it appears you cannot get an S rank on individually criteria but it is possible overall, perhaps the requirement is to get all A ranks for each category

Comment: Just for confirmation after having spent much more time with this game, I can confirm that an overall 'S' rank does require all 'A' ranks for individual categories. I have had 3 A's and a B a couple of times and this results in only an 'A' rank overall

Answer (score 0):

You can die at least twice per chapter to get Death - A Rank.

I try to get keep my accuracy at 80% get an Accuracy - A Rank.

Get through the chapter as fast to get Clear Time - A Rank.

Kill as many enemies as possible without taking a long time to get Enemies Routed - A Rank.

The best way to get a lot of kills fast is by getting infinite ammo for a strong weapon (Shotgun, Magnum, etc.) and use quick shot a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the time matters that much.  The most important factors are how many enemies are killed and especially the accuracy; how well you aim at the enemies.  You shouldn't do "straight bullet"... missing shots will definitely decrease your chance to get an "S". Try to kill them with no misses; critical hits are good, but the upper body is better for a novice!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rank A in 4 ratings to get an S rank.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Thanks for taking the time to answer this question, but there are already answers to this question that provide the same information. Have a look at some of the unanswered questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer, you just need an A rank in the 4 categories.  You can't get an S in each category, as obviously a zero death would count as an S, but if you get a B in any category, you'll get an A or less instead of the S.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. The first part of your answer is simply pointing out something that has already been assumed from the information provided in Aubergines answer and not providing any additional information. The second part also appears to be a assumption. Can you provide a source or do some research to verify this?